# Returning constructor arguments in braces?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, return, curly-braces

The brace initialization (or uniform init) really is confusing. What exactly happens when a function returns a list of arguments in braces?

```cpp
std::vector<double> foo()
{
    //is this the same as: std::vector<double>{1, 2}
    //or std::vector<double>(1, 2)?
    //or something else?
    return {1, 2};
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`return {1, 2};`, the return value is [list-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) from `{1, 2}`, as the effect, the returned `std::vector<double>` contains 2 elements with value `1` and `2`.

`return std::vector<double>{1, 2};`, the return value is [copy-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from `std::vector<double>{1, 2}`, as the effect, the returned `std::vector<double>` contains 2 elements with value `1` and `2`. In concept it'll construct a temporary `std::vector<double>` and the return value is copy-initialized from the temporary; because of [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17) the copy/move operation is ommitted and the effect is exactly the same as the 1st case.

`return std::vector<double>(1, 2)`, the return value is copy-initialized from `std::vector<double>(1, 2)`, as the effect, the returned `std::vector<double>` contains 1 elements with value `2`. Mandatory copy elision takes effect in this case too.

Comment: so returning {1, 2} is the equivalent of calling std::vector<double> temporary{1, 2}? The rest invole a copy?

Comment: @lucmobz The effect is the same due to [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17).

Comment: Ok, but if they're equivalent, then returning by braces saves typing the type name?

Comment: @lucmobz Yes, less typing.